# Div bounces or rolls as you scroll down page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking at this site and also have seen other sites do it. Images, divs, contact buttons etc all either bounce or roll in as the viewport goes down. I have been looking all over for this script or a demo that I can download and use on my sites. Any thoughts? The site url is brdesignlab.com

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean then I think a jQuery plugin like Scrollorama might do the trick: http://plugins.jquery.com/Scrollorama/

There's a demo page link on the plugin page:
http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/